# MONGO mongodb script to replace a substring from a array element

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

```
{
  field:"value",
  facilityId:"H001",
  alternativeId:["deafaultID#12312-213-1314"],
}
```

I want to replace all the document  "defaultID" from the array of `alternativeId` and change to "NEWID" only if the facilityId is "H001"

Comment: you can use `$replaceOne` and `$map` operators.

Comment: how.. can you give me a example

Answer (score 2):

- match `facilityId: "H001"` condition
- `$map` to iterate loop of `alternativeId` array
- `$replaceOne` to replace find string by replacement

```
db.collection.update(
  { facilityId: "H001" },
  [{
    $set: {
      alternativeId: {
        $map: {
          input: "$alternativeId",
          in: {
            $replaceOne: {
              input: "$$this",
              find: "deafaultID",
              replacement: "NEWID"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }],
  { multi: true }
)
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HG2P1DH6GnV)

Comment: i edited my qstn . actually i want to check facilityid as condition or filter. only replace the alternativID of a specified facilityID

Comment: okay you want to update in database or just need to format result only?

Comment: @Alfjoy have you checked updated answer it is working?